# Copy/pasted text from web into vi displays weird characters

Tags: php, ascii, vi

Try copy/pasting this line into vi.

South—Parishioners of Pastor Theo Leobald’s First

It will look like this: South▒~@~TParishioners of Pastor Theo Leobald▒~@~Ys First

It displays a bunch of weird characters that I cannot figure out how to get rid of.  I tried doing html_entity_decode in php, but that did not do anything.

```
    $out = html_entity_decode ($text_converted);
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the example.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with the following code:

```
$text = "South▒^▒^▒Parishioners of Pastor Theo Leobald▒^▒^▒s First";
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text), PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Because `—` and `’` is a special character. perhaps manually remove it.